# Under which circumstances would ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent not fire?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to build a DiscoveryClient and I want it to fire an event when there is a change to the routes.  I am using

```
publisher.publishEvent(new InstanceRegisteredEvent<>(this, "serviceName"));
```

However, the event does not actually fire even if it is the same object.  I am suspecting it is because it is a different thread, but `@Scheduled` also run from a different thread and it fires successfuly.

Answer (score 1):

The circumstance that I hit was the fact that I was using the ApplicationEventPublisher that was provided during the BootstrapAutoConfiguration phase in the application.  Because I was using that, the events I publish do not get propagated as expected.

To get around that I had to make sure to change the ApplicationEventPublisher that was have put in during bootstrap with something after by adding in another AutoConfiguration executed during the AutoConfiguration phase and not in Bootstrap phase.

I added (but it is optional) `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` to the class in my case `DockerSwarmDiscovery`

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(DockerSwarmDiscovery.class)
@Slf4j
public class DockerSwarmDiscoveryWatchAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DockerSwarmDiscovery dockerSwarmDiscovery;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @PostConstruct
    public void injectPublisher() {
        dockerSwarmDiscovery.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    }

}
```